# golang TestMain() function sets variable that can't be accessed by tests

Tags: testing, go

I've got the following TestMain function:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
  db := "[working_db_connection]"
  dbInstance, _ := InitializeRepo(db, 2)
  runTests := m.Run()
  os.Exit(runTests)
}
```

and the following sample test

```
func TestSomeFeature(t *testing.T) {
  fmt.Println(dbInstance)
}
```

The function TestSomeFeature does run, but says dbInstance is undefined. Why would this not have access to the variable? From examples I'm seeing variables et in TestMain are accessed with this syntax.

Answer (score 12):

`dbInstance` is a local variable of `TestMain` and it doesn't exist in the lifecycle of `TestSomeFeature` function. and for this reason the test suite says to you that `dbInstance` is undefined.
Define the variable as global variable outside TestMain and then instantiate the variable in the TestMain

```
var DbInstance MyVariableRepoType

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
  db := "[working_db_connection]"
  DbInstance, _ = InitializeRepo(db, 2)
  runTests := m.Run()
  os.Exit(runTests)
}
```

Comment: If we do this, does the `DbInstance` get exported as part of the package?

Comment: Yes, if you care about variable export, you have to change the variable name to dbInstance.

Comment: isn't it bad practice to define global variable? I just get rejection on my code review and required to use suite package.

Answer (score 4):

You should have your variable defined outside of any function.

```
var dbInstance DbType
```